# How to convert a string to object and loop in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, foreach

I have a object which I am getting from database

Note: The below array is the output of `console.log(ansoptions)`;

```
[{id:1, option:"Yes"},{id:2, option:"No"},{id:3, option:"Other"}]
```

This initially is in datatype string. I want to convert it into array of objects and loop to get id and option values.

I have tried below code

```
var ansoptions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props.answerOptions));
console.log(ansoptions);
Array.from(ansoptions, item => {
console.log(item);
})
```

For the `console.log(item)` I am getting the output as weird as below

```
    [
    {
    i
    d
    :
    1
    ,
     
    o
    p
```

and so on.....

How do I get it? Please help !!

Comment: The JSON. parse() method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string.

The JSON. stringify() method converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string.

So if you are getting string datatype you should use JSON.parse(yourStringDataType), this will convert it to object.

Comment: @Aldin I am getting an error if I do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the JSON (a string), then just loop over the array that's created.

```js
const json = '[{"id":1, "option":"Yes"},{"id":2, "option":"No"},{"id":3, "option":"Other"}]';

const arr = JSON.parse(json);

for (let obj of arr) {
  console.log(obj.id, obj.option);
}
```